# Clojure Unit Testing for Java in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, clojure, leiningen

I'm writing unit-tests in Clojure for a Java library I'm working on.

I'm just writing the tests in separate project that refers to my Java project, running them from the command line with Lein.

But I'm now going back to work on some Android code in Android Studio.

I'd like to continue the same practice there. Ie. writing tests in Clojure.

Is there a way to integrate this into Android Studio (ie. write the Clojure code in Android Studio and compile / run it against the Android project)?

Comment: Take a look at the Cursive plugin for Intellij Idea https://cursive-ide.com/

Comment: Thanks. But I'm on Android Studio :-(

Comment: Android Studio is based on IntelliJ.

Comment: I know. But does that mean I can add any IntelliJ plugin to Android Studio?

Comment: Yes. You can install the Cursive plugin in Android Studio.